# RSA public key generation interoperability between Android and plain Java

Tags: java, android, rsa

I have created a public/private keypair in my app and encoded (Base 64) the public key. I then imported the encoded string in a database table (mysql).

In a servlet I read the encoded string and decode it to get back the original byte sequence.

I have verified that the original byte sequence for the public key is the same in my app and in my servlet - well at least the first 10 bytes and the last 10 bytes. I assume that the inner part of the byte array (length is 294 bytes) should be the same.

I then try to create a valid RSAPublicKey based on that byte array using the following method:

```
    public static RSAPublicKey createPublicKey(byte [] publicKeyData)

{
    KeyFactory keyFactory;
    RSAPublicKey newKey = null;

    try
    {
        keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        X509EncodedKeySpec KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyData);
      newKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(KeySpec);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InvalidKeySpecException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newKey;
}
```

This is my code on the Android side:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
  kpGenerator.initialize(spec);
  KeyPair kp = kpGenerator.generateKeyPair();
  PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
  PublicKey publicKey = kp.getPublic();
  KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

  byte[] res = publicKey.getEncoded();
  String pubKeyString;

  pubKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(res, Base64.NO_WRAP);
  System.out.println("Public Key (Base64):" + pubKeyString
```

However when I compare the modulus value from the calculated RSAPublicKey and the one created in my app, I get different values.

I have already tried to create a second RSAPublicKey from the byte array in my Android App - which I found identical to the original one - so I assume the method for creating a public key from a byte array should be ok.

I suspect that there might be implementation issues between Android (which seems to be based on SSL) and the servlet (which is based on Java 8).

Any ideas what's going on here and how can I solve the issues here?

Any hints would be very welcome!

Rudi

Comment: You are going to have to verify all 294 bytes.

Comment: If you properly encoded the public keys they should be completely interoperable. Please show the code where the public key is encoded on the Android side. Also, did you ever base64 decode the key data on the Java side?

Comment: I added the Android code in my original posting. And yes, I did decode the key data on the Java side.

Comment: Finally could compare the files - they are really different, the first 34 bytes being identical and the last bytes too - so now I have to find out why there's a difference...

Comment: Finally I have had a little time to track the problem - it really was due to some kind of typo - there has been a wrong value in the database against which I compared the encoded public key. The key was mostly identical - at least the first and the last bytes - however there were differences in the  middle part. Don't know why  - I would have thought that the key would be completely different - I really had to compare all the key as EJP mentioned. @EJB: Thanks for pointing out this issue.